Installing Literaturnaya font for Tectonic
Is it possible to install the literaturnaya font, so that it can be used by the tectonic compiler?
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cyrillic/literat/

I think you might be able to, but you really don't want to use these fonts with a Unicode engine. Find a Unicode version, use pdfTeX or pick another font.
